# Which service is doing load balancing between kubernetes nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the entry point in k8s cluster? How is request routed from entry point to certain container?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very general, you have many types of load balancers (internal, 3rd party, Ingresses ...)

But the best answer is Kubernetes [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) since all of the above relays on them.

A service in kubernetes is a set of  Linux iptables (or IPVS) rules that will execute a Destination Network Address Translation (DNAT) on the packets going to specific Ip addresses. In short:

1- A service will have a virtual IP address called ServiceIP or ClusterIP.

2- The user communicates with kubernetes [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) (single container or set of related containers) using the clusterIP.

3- The Iptables in the node will forward the packets with the destination   ClusteIP to the IP address of the associated Pod using a [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/).

The load balancing is done through the iptables, where each service will have an Iptables rule:

```
 # iptables -t nat -L KUBE-SERVICES 
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination  
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.104.192.249       /* default/hypriot: cluster IP */ tcp dpt:http
KUBE-SVC-IKNY2FZN6EXMQQCV  tcp  --  anywhere             10.104.192.249       /* default/hypriot: cluster IP */ tcp dpt:http

# kubectl get svc hypriot
NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
hypriot   ClusterIP   10.104.192.249   <none>        80/TCP    11d
```

For this example, the deployment hypriot have a ClusterIP `10.104.192.249`, the second iptables rule will forward all the packets with this destination Ip toward the CHAIN `KUBE-SVC-IKNY2FZN6EXMQQCV`.

To see what this CHAIN will do:

```
# iptables -t nat -L KUBE-SVC-IKNY2FZN6EXMQQCV
Chain KUBE-SVC-IKNY2FZN6EXMQQCV (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SEP-JEK5XLX6ULDDGJAZ  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/hypriot: */ statistic mode random probability 0.33332999982
KUBE-SEP-WTXTLPWDUQWUHKOF  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/hypriot: */ statistic mode random probability 0.50000000000
KUBE-SEP-OQ7KPRR3BI2AFITK  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/hypriot: */
```

Each of the KUBE-SEP is a Service EndPoint which represents the address of a pod, where for this deployment hypriot  has 3 replicas.

```
# kubectl get endpoints hypriot
NAME      ENDPOINTS                                       AGE
hypriot   10.244.1.14:80,10.244.2.21:80,10.244.3.153:80   11d
# kubectl get po -o wide 
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
hypriot-587768b4f5-9dq2k   1/1       Running   0          11d       10.244.2.21    node03
hypriot-587768b4f5-czd86   1/1       Running   0          11d       10.244.3.153   node04
hypriot-587768b4f5-j22sh   1/1       Running   0          11d       10.244.1.14    node02
```

One of these Endpoints will be chosen and the packet will be forwarded to the associated KUBE-SEP CHAIN:

```
# iptables -t nat -L KUBE-SEP-JEK5XLX6ULDDGJAZ
Chain KUBE-SEP-JEK5XLX6ULDDGJAZ (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.1.14          anywhere             /* default/hypriot: */
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* default/hypriot: */ tcp to:10.244.1.14:80
```

This is the last piece of the puzzle where the DNAT will occur and the new destination will be the selected pod IP (`10.244.1.14` for the pod `hypriot-587768b4f5-j22sh` in this example), when another service Endpoint is selected, the packet will be DNATed to another pod.

you can use Iptables `-v` flag to check the rules that are used which will help you in the understanding process.

Some good reads: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/ 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables