# Expose each pod in a statefulset to the internet without a custom proxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a StatefulSet with pods `server-0`, `server-1`, etc. I want to expose them directly to the internet with URLs like server-0.mydomain.com or like mydomain.com/server-0.

I want to be able to scale the StatefulSet and automatically be able to access the new pods from the internet. For example, if I scale it up to include a `server-2`, I want mydomain.com/server-2 to route requests to the new pod when it's ready. I don't want to have to also scale some other resource or create another Service to achieve that effect.

I could achieve this with a custom proxy service that just checks the request path and forwards to the correct pod internally, but this seems error-prone and wasteful.

Is there a way to cause an Ingress to automatically route to different pods within a StatefulSet, or some other built-in technique that would avoid custom code?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it. Being part of the same statefulSet, all pods up to pod-x, are targeted by a service. As you can't define which pod is going to get a request, you can't force "pod-1.yourapp.com" or "yourapp.com/pod-1" to be sent to pod-1. It will be sent to the service, and the service might sent it to pod-4.

Even though if you could, you would need to dynamically update your ingress rules, which can cause a downtime of minutes, easily.

With the custom proxy, I see it impossible too. Note that it would need to basically replace the service behind the pods. If your ingress controller knows that it needs to deliver a packet to a service, now you have to force it to deliver to your proxy. But how?

Comment: I'm imagining a simple proxy service that reads the requested url and decides what pod to proxy to. This should be simple with pod dns names, right? Ingress -> proxy service -> proxy pod -> server-3.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local right?

Answer (score 1):

A Kubernetes service is a set of iptables (or IPVS) rules that will redirect a packet with the ServiceIP as a destination address to **ONE OF THE PODS** that have the same label. [image]

from [Kubernetes Services documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables)

> The service installs iptables rules which select a backend Pod. By default, the choice of backend is random.

Which refers to the fact that a service is not able to distinguish between different pods in the same set.

If you want to force the selection of a specific Pod out of the set by changing the iprules (fairly simple), or by adding any type of proxy is problematic: 
    let's say you configured `pod-1` and `pod-2` (`1.1.1.1` and `1.1.1.2` respectively), and you configured iptables rules to DNAT requests with destination `pod-1.myserver.com` to `1.1.1.1` and same for pod-2. (you may ask why the IP, and it's simply because it's the only way to distinguish between these pods)
This approach will fail whenever a pod restarts, let's say pod-1 failed, Kubernetes won't recreate the same pod with same IP and name, instead will create pod-3 with a different IP and updates the iptables accordingly. As a result, all the packets going toward 1.1.1.1 will be dropped until you update the proxy or iptables again.

In fact, that's one of the reasons why we use service to access pods instead of accessing them directly since the Pod IP can change however the service IP won't.

However, since this very specific part of kubernetes was my work for the last 4 months, I have developed a [python script](https://github.com/alijawadfahs/FOG-aware) to edit the iptables and to choose a specific pod, my conclusion of that work was it's costy and time-consuming and will impose the server to go offline for a couple of seconds when the pods are changed, you can take a look at the code, it definitely works but its not recommended.

This problem is a kubernetes problem and the solution is changing the source code of Kube-proxy, which is my current work.

I suggest you read my answer explaining how kubernetes services exactly work in this question: [Which service is doing load balancing between kubernetes nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758122/which-service-is-doing-load-balancing-between-kubernetes-nodes/50760654#50760654)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. With StatefulSets I believe that pods will be recreated with the exact same name, so I should at least be able to proxy to them reliably (although of course connections will fail while pods are down).

Comment: The Ip address of a rescheduled Pod will change even if the pod is in a statefulset, how you are going to forward according to the name, using DNS you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly, with DNS. I haven't done this before so it's just a thought, but it seems like it should work?